# Add SafeArea into SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make FlexibleSpaceBar in SliverAppBar honour SafeArea?.

```
CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
              title: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/user.png')),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              TextField(),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      )
```

I need the image be below os header at all time

[image]

I tried to wrap it with SafeArea widget but that didn't work and crashed

Comment: Have you wrapped your `CustomScrollView` into `SafeArea`

Comment: @NileshRathod By doing that the whole app bar is shifted.. I only need tho shift the content of FlexibleSpaceBar

Comment: What if we use [SliverToBoxAdapter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverToBoxAdapter-class.html) before the `SliverAppBar` to create the required space?

Comment: @dev-aentgs hmm.. haven't tried that.. Not sure if that will make desired effect though

Comment: @delmin Also did you use `SafeArea` or [SliverSafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverSafeArea-class.html)  ?

Comment: @delmin I don't think you can wrap your SliverAppBar with SafeArea since it will not display any content below the SafeArea. I think you're only solutions are to wrap CustomScrollView with SafeArea or you can add a SliverToBoxAdapter with color blue with the same height as the appbar but then this means that when you scroll futher down below the SliverToBoxAdapter will be hidden.

Comment: @dev-aentgs I just tried SliverSafeArea and the only place I was able to wrap SliverAppBar. It doesn't work anywhere else and that will move the whole AppBar which I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
class TestSafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate(
                  expandedHeight: 200,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/YOUR_IMAGE.png'))),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              TextField(),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget child;

  final double expandedHeight;

  SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate({this.child, this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SafeArea(bottom: false, child: SizedBox.expand(child: child));
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate old) {
    if (old.child != child) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: If you need a colour for your header, just wrap the safearea widget in a coloured container :)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and definitely deserve upvote. This last answer looks promising however when scrolling sliver list up then it gets into the abbbar.. Any idea how to fixed that?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'gets into appbar'?

Comment: if you scroll content of SliverList to top then the content of that List is above the AppBar and goes all the way to the top of the screen. It should be hidden behind the app bar

Comment: If you wrap the SafeArea in a container with a color - then the list should be hidden by the header

Comment: BTW I've noticed that actually both solution works as expected but when you try to put more then one widget into the flexibleArea in other words wrapping the image into a column then the image expand and doesn't scale.. I can not figure out how to add more then one widget there. I need to add a text at the bottom of the image and keep scaling untouched. The perfect solution would be display the text when expanded and remove it when collapsed. Any idea how to do it? here is the reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445009/mimic-ios-contact-form-appbar

Answer (score 1):

EDIT #2 - Just saw you don't want the entire AppBar in the SafeArea

```
class SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget title;

  final Widget flexibleSpace;

  final double expandedHeight;

  SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate(
      {this.title, this.flexibleSpace, this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final Widget appBar = FlexibleSpaceBar.createSettings(
      minExtent: minExtent,
      maxExtent: maxExtent,
      currentExtent: max(minExtent, maxExtent - shrinkOffset),
      toolbarOpacity: 1,
      child: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: title,
          flexibleSpace: (title == null && flexibleSpace != null)
              ? Semantics(child: flexibleSpace, header: true)
              : flexibleSpace,
          toolbarOpacity: 1,
          bottomOpacity: 1.0),
    );
    return appBar;
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate old) {
    if (old.flexibleSpace != flexibleSpace) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will give your desired effect.
By using a SliverPersistentHeader with a custom SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate that returns an AppBar wrapped in the SafeArea widget.

```
class TestSafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: SafeAreaPersistentHeaderDelegate(
                expandedHeight: 200,
                flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              TextField(),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My bad - I will quickly review

Comment: @delmin please see now

Comment: hmm ... let me try it

Comment: Made slight change after seeing you don't want entire app bar to be shifted - only the contents, please see again

Comment: If you don't want to have space at bottom, include `bottom:false` to your safearea.

Comment: See other answer