# Animation in SliverAppBar => resize bar dynamically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I got a `SliverAppBar` with an `AnimatedContainer` inside. The height of this animated container changes on runtime, so the container animates its resizing. My problem is, that the `expandedHeight` of my SliverAppBar is fix. But this needs to resize analog to my animated Container.

Is there a way to set the SliverAppBar to "height is always according to child" or something like that? The AnimatedContainer has no callback which gives me every change while it animates the resizing. If there would be such a callback I could change the `expandedHeight` attribute of the SliverAppBar accordingly by myself.

Any idea how to fix my problem? Thanks!

```
return SliverAppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      snap: true,
      pinned: false,
      floating: true,
      forceElevated: false,
      primary: false,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      expandedHeight: _eHeight,
      flexibleSpace: Column(children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedContainer(
            onEnd: onTopBarsAnimationEnd,
            height: _trending
                ? _tabBarHeight: _tabBarHeight + topicsHeight,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            child: // some child
            )
        ]
    )
)
```

**Edit - Here is a gif showing what I want to achieve:**
[image]

Comment: I think I have answered a similar question not long time ago.. check if that will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445009/mimic-ios-contact-form-appbar/62497897#62497897

Comment: @LonelyWolf I think (I might be mistaken) that this is something different. The AnimatedContainer is not triggered by scrolling something from the scrollbar. I know these effects of SliverAppBar.

Comment: hmm... I apologise then.. can you please include some gif video into your question what you want to achieve for better understanding of your question

Comment: @LonelyWolf no reason to apologize. I added some gif that shows what I want to achieve. When clicking the button my 'animatedContainer' expands and changes the height. Accordingly the expandedHeight of my SliverAppBar should expand like in the gif.

Comment: as far as I can see from you gif I can see that you're experiencing the same problem I had.. If you put some animated widget into sliver AppBar than the animation of that widget will interfere with the sliver animation. I had that problem with CircularAvatar which apparently has built in animation. I would suggest you do it without SliverAppBar and use Animated container as you do, or get rid of the animated container in the SliverAppBar

Comment: BTW please post your solution here.. for others...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect [AnimatedContainer docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html), they say:

> This class is useful for generating simple **implicit** transitions between different parameters to Container with its **internal AnimationController**. For more complex animations, you'll likely want to use a subclass of **AnimatedWidget** such as the DecoratedBoxTransition or use your own AnimationController.

Here, 'implicit' means you are not going to control the animation and thus, you are not going to be able to access the [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) class that is going to allow you to listen the animation steps. To do it, you are going to need something like [AnimatedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html).

A deeper look into AnimationController reveals it inherits from ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget, which docs say:

> ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgets (and their subclasses) automatically animate changes in their properties whenever they change. For this, they create and manage their own **internal AnimationControllers** to power the animation. While these widgets are simple to use and don't require you to manually manage the lifecycle of an AnimationController, they are also somewhat **limited**: Besides the target value for the animated property, developers can only chose a duration and curve for the animation. If you require more control over the animation (e.g. you want to stop it somewhere in the middle), consider using a **AnimatedWidget** or one of its subclasses. These widget take an Animation as an argument to power the animation. This gives the developer full control over the animation at the cost of requiring you to manually manage the underlying AnimationController.

So what you need is to create your AnimatedController object and pass it to an AnimatedWidget. You can see an example in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html).

Finally, to do something in each animation step, you need to add a listener function to the AnimatedController using its method **addListener**, what usually is done in the initState method of your widget.