# Flutter Sticky widget that belongs to ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to have a sticky widget similar to the floating widgets in scaffolds, difference is that this widget would belong to a ListView, when it isn't on screen it would behave as a floating widget, when user scrolls so its position be visible it would start animating to stay on its position on the ListView.

Here is a visual example of what I am trying to achieve
https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*GsH-kEVNtoDZaM0ZjNYRpQ.gif (the 'MY STICKY BUTTON' widget)

is this even possible in flutter ? and if so how ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to use slivers... look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445009/mimic-ios-contact-form-appbar